# Symbian S60 Code Editor

Tags: editor, s60, codehighlighter

I am looking for an app that will let me type in code ON my cellphone. I don't need to compile or anything, and its not to program for the cellphone. Just something nice to have when an idea pops in my head.

Am I completely overlooking a simple code editor for Symbian S60v3 phones?

I am looking for something similar to [CEdit](http://www.logicalsky.com/Product_CEdit.php) which is for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [pyEdit](http://users.tkk.fi/~lhuovine/mobile/python.html) on my S60v2 phone, it looks like it's supported under v3 as well.

It depends on the python runtime, so you'll need to install that first.

Answer (score 2):

Try [YEdit](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Text-editors/yEdit.shtml) or [LightNotepad](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Word-Processing-Text-Tools/Text-Editor/LightNotepad-65432.shtml)

Comment: There is a missing 'l' in your link to YEdit.

Answer (score 1):

try `ped-s60`

http://code.google.com/p/ped-s60/downloads/list

Answer (score -2):

You can use visual studio :

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Using_Visual_Studio_6.0_with_S60_3rd_Edition

Answer (score -2):

You can download the very basic edition of Carbide C++ **for free** from [Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Tools/IDEs/Carbide/)

This is built on the eclipse platform and is very good.